# Connection detector returns false through background service

Tags: android, android-service, android-connectivitymanager

In my application I want to get GPS location of through a foregrond service and receiver. every thing is running fine but after two or three successful run. service is not able to detect internet and returns false

here is the code

Code for receiver of calling service in activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent ll24 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent recurringLl24 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, ll24, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,0, 30*10*100, recurringLl24);
   }
 //.....
}
```

& in receiver class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver 
{   
    static Context context;
    Date curTime,sdf,edf;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ForegroundService";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        try 
        {
            Calendar c =  Calendar.getInstance();
            curTime =  new SimpleDateFormat( "HH:mm" ).parse(c.get( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+c.get( Calendar.MINUTE));
            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "HH:mm" ).parse("08:00");
            edf = new SimpleDateFormat( "HH:mm" ).parse("20:00");    
            if(curTime.after(sdf) && curTime.before(edf))
            {
                Intent ll24Service = new Intent(context, ForegroundService.class);
                ll24Service.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
                ForegroundService.IS_SERVICE_RUNNING = true;
                startWakefulService(context,ll24Service);   
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
```

in service class

```
public class ForegroundService extends Service 
{
...
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
    AlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) 
    {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Start Foreground Intent ");
        showNotification();

        Calendar c =  Calendar.getInstance();
        curDateTime  = c.get( Calendar.YEAR)+"-"+ String.valueOf(c.get( Calendar.MONTH )+1)+"-"+ c.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+" "+c.get( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+c.get( Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+c.get( Calendar.SECOND);

        gps = new GPS(ForegroundService.this);
        if(gps.canGetLocation())
        {
            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            latt=Double.toString(latitude);
            longi =String.valueOf(longitude);

            insertData();   
        }
        else
        {
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }   
    } 

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In onDestroy");
}

private void insertData() 
{
    try
    {
        String QUERY = "insert into GpsLoc values('"+usr+"','"+latt+"','"+longi+"','"+curDateTime+"')";
        myDatabase.execSQL(QUERY);

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "insert");
        ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
        Boolean isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

        if(isInternetPresent)
        {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "chk int");
            addToJason();
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "No int");
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
        }



    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data not inserted : "+ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Every thing is running fine as shown in the log:

> 03-19 12:11:48.160: I/ForegroundService(17476): Received Start
>   Foreground Intent
>
> 03-19 12:11:48.270: D/Network(17476): Network
>
> 03-19 12:11:48.340: I/ForegroundService(17476): insert
>
> 03-19 12:11:48.390: I/ForegroundService(17476): chk int
>
> 03-19 12:11:49.340: I/ForegroundService(17476): uploaded
>
> 03-19 12:11:49.350: I/ForegroundService(17476): In onDestroy

But after two or three run same log became

> 03-19 12:15:34.670: I/ForegroundService(17476): Received Start Foreground Intent
>
> 03-19 12:15:34.740: D/Network(17476): Network
>
> 03-19 12:15:34.780: I/ForegroundService(17476): insert
>
> 03-19 12:15:34.780: I/ForegroundService(17476): No int
>
> 03-19 12:15:34.850: I/ForegroundService(17476): In onDestroy

the problem is at checking internet connection while app is not running and it is called through service. Please suggest any solution

Some times it throuws :

> 03-27 12:30:07.240: I/ForegroundService(1543):
>   android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window --
>   token null is not for an application

and some times : Error converting result jsonobject

Please help Problem Strat Here when we called to detect internet in service

```
ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
Boolean isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
```

Comment: Use FirebaseJobDispatcher.

Comment: any example refernce

Answer (score 1):

Add this dependency in your `gradle` file.

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
```

Create a `Firebase` `JobService` File and declare in `manifest`.

```
<service
        android:exported="false"
        android:name="._User_Classes.User_Call_Record.ScheduledJobService">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.ACTION_EXECUTE"/>
        </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Declare and start the `JobService` from your `activity` or fragment

```
FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(this));
        Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setService(ScheduledJobService.class) // the JobService that will be called
                .setRecurring(false) //repeat the job or not

                .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 60))
                .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
                .setTag("demo")        // uniquely identifies the job
                .build();
        dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```

Below is the `JobService` class which will be called each time the job is executed.

```
public class ScheduledJobService extends JobService {

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters job) {
    if(isConnected(this))
{
//internet available
}
else{
//internet not available
}
       //perform your operations
        FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new 
        GooglePlayDriver(this));
        Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setService(ScheduledJobService.class) // the JobService that will be called
                .setRecurring(false) //repeat the job or not
                .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 60))
                .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
                .setTag("demo")        // uniquely identifies the job
                .build();
        dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
        return true;
    }






    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
        return false;
    }

 public static NetworkInfo getNetworkInfo(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    }

    /**
     * Check if there is any connectivity
     *
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        NetworkInfo info = getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected());
    }

}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am working in eclipse. i will try to change with this code in eclipse. If you can send me how to implement this in eclipse will help me lot

Comment: Code does not change whether you use eclipse or android studio

Comment: what to about this compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'

Comment: I am not aware of how to add dependencies in the eclipse project. You can check some other thread about adding dependencies.

Comment: I tried a lot but finally i am not able to add dependency in eclipse.

Comment: Can't you migrate to android studio ?

Comment: Not working Same error is showing even it is not even run after two or three attempt

Comment: Have you been able to run this in eclipse ?

Comment: No i tried this in android studio but it is not running continuously

Comment: You can set recurring to false and then in start job method again start the new job the same way you are doing in activity, I also do this way in my application , I again set the same job from startJobMethod, I am editing my answer

Comment: Check the log problem is remain after two or three run it gives 
03-23 16:37:56.668 31322-31322/track.gps.lipi.mygpstrack I/GpsJob: latt
03-23 16:37:56.668 31322-31322/track.gps.lipi.mygpstrack I/GpsJob: usr
03-23 16:37:56.698 31322-31322/track.gps.lipi.mygpstrack I/GpsJob: insert
03-23 16:37:56.718 31322-31322/track.gps.lipi.mygpstrack I/GpsJob: No int

Comment: Problem is not with running a job problem is detection of internet which is not resolving

Comment: remove the constraint from the code , then it will run on any network whether connected or not, then in the service check for internet availability

Comment: same log is coming no change